# Indefinite leave to remain. Working abroad

Tags: united-kingdom

I read that a person may lose ILR by leaving the United Kingdom for more than two years.

Does this apply also to an employee who continued to pay taxes in the UK, continued to work by a British company, but was asked to work abroad, at the client site, by his employer?

Comment: If you are an EU citizen you would apply for settled status, which you would have to do anyway, and which gives you five years. I don’t know the laws of all countries, but if you worked in Germany for over two years, you would be a tax resident and would have to pay tax in Germany.